# How to design the classes with OOP?

Tags: class, oop

I have problems about classes design now. The question is as follows:

I want to design classes for fruit and juicer. The classes for fruit (Apple, pear peach) are done. Now I want to design classes for juicer.

The requirement for juicer are:

1.Juicers take specific fruit (apple, pear, peach) and produce juice. NOTE: there may be mixed juice (such as flavor of apple and pear).

2.One kind of juicer can only produce one kind of juice.

3.Juicers have space to store fruit, and we can know how many apples or pears are still there. (We assume that every time one juicer uses one apple or pear).

Could anyone give me some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark's answer is pretty good and a good start... I'd expand a bit. I probably wouldn't use an array for fruits since you will be adding, removing etc... probably easier to implement with a list or similar. Also, Laine says he wants multiple fruits in some juicers.. that complicates things a bit and gives us some decisions to make.

If it will always be a maximum of two fruits, I would probably just make two juicer classes similar to those in Mark's answer:

```
public interface IFruit
{
    string Name {get;}
}

public class Apple : IFruit
{
    public string Name { get {return "Apple";} }
}

public class Pear : IFruit
{
    public string Name { get {return "Pear";} }
}

public class Juicer<IFruit>
{
    private IList<IFruit> fruits;

    public Juicer(IList<IFruit> fruits)
    {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }

    public int FruitCount
    {
        get { return this.fruits.Count; }
    }

    // Other members can go here...
}


public class TwoFruitJuicer<IFruit, IFruit2>
{
    private IList<IFruit> fruits;
    private IList<IFruit2> fruits2;

    public TwoFruitJuicer(IList<IFruit> fruits, IList<IFruit2> fruits2)
    {
        this.fruits = fruits;
        this.fruits2 = fruits2;
    }

    public int FruitCount
    {
        get { return this.fruits.Count + this.fruits2.Count; }
    }

    // Other members can go here...
}
```

But, say you wanted 3 or 4 different juicers combined...

```
public class MulitJuicer
{
    private IList<Juicer<IFruit>> _juicers;

    public MulitJuicer(IList<Juicer<IFruit>> juicers)
    {
        this._juicers = juicers;    
    }

    public int FruitCount
    {
        get {

            int allFruitCount = 0;

            foreach (var j in _juicers)
            {
                allFruitCount += j.FruitCount;
            }

            return allFruitCount;
        }
    }
}
```

However, That would probably be pretty difficult to use, a lot of lists inside of lists to keep track of build up and whatnot... what if you wanted just once juicer that you could just dump a bunch of fruits in? We can use Reflection to verify that only allowed fruits are put in the juicer:

```
public class MultiFruitJuicer
{
    private IList<Type> _juiceTypes;
    private IList<IFruit> _fruits;

    public MultiFruitJuicer(IList<Type> juiceTypes, IList<IFruit> fruits)
    {
        _juiceTypes = juiceTypes;
        _fruits = fruits;

        if (!ValidateFruits())
        {
            //you may not want to actually throw here...
            throw new Exception("Not all proper fruit types");
        }
    }

    public bool ValidateFruits()
    {
        //there are about a million ways to do this... this is probably not the best...
        foreach(var f in _fruits)
        {
            if (!_juiceTypes.Contains(f.GetType()))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int FruitCount
    {
        get { return this._fruits.Count; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your language supports [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming) (as do C# and Java), the simplest solution would be to make the Juicer generic:

```
public class Juicer<T>
{
    private T[] fruits;

    public Juicer(T[] fruits)
    {
        this.fruits = fruits;
    }

    public FruitCount
    {
        get { return this.fruits.Length; }
    }

    // Other members can go here...
}
```

You can create one object that's a `Juicer<Apple>`, another as a `Juicer<Pear>`, and so on. A `Juicer<Apple>` can only contain `Apple` objects, etc.

Comment: One of the requirements was mixed juice, so variable-length generics (like C++11 templates or at least manual expansion to a reasonable number of parameters) would be required. Or maybe it could be formed by composing two regular juicers together, but that's pretty unclear from the Q I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by implementing [Builder design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/builder-design-pattern) for the

> design classes for juicer

It'll help you to construct a complex object (juice) and separate its representation, so that the same construction process can create different representations (kinds of juice).

Add some interface (IFruit) and base class (shared code for Weight, Size etc.) to

> classes for fruit (Apple, pear peach)

Each Juicer will have

```
ICollection<IFruit> fruits
```

that can be managed - `.Count()`, `.Add(IFruit)` or `.Remove(IFruit)`.

Comment: Two things that made me downvote this answer were **a)** an unbased Singleton recommendation in 2015 **b)** There's no indication that forcing fruit under a common interface and/or a base class is justified. This has a disadvantage of closing the juicer access from types added without knowing this code. If anything, I'd expect a type-erased access to generic juicers, something the other answer recommends.

Comment: @bartek The `Fruit` interface will make sure that if new fruit types are added, the rest of the code will still work with it - `Juicer`. Further more it'll allow you to have a collection of fruits. The base class will help avoid the repetition of the common for all fruits fields, properties, methods.

Comment: But that also means you won't be able to adapt any classes that don't inherit from the Fruir or implement fruit interface without writing complex adapters, which can be avoided by using generics.

Comment: Which exactly Fruit classes will not inherit or implement the fruit functionality? Are they fruits at all? What about the [Liskov substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) ?

Comment: There might be types outside of your code that you don't know about that might satisfy being a fruit. The fact that you can't easily write interface implementations for foreign classes makes interfaces much less useful. If we're talking about a language with open interfaces, then such an interface is fine, but the base class for fruit shouldn't be a necessity then, more like a convenience.

Comment: Making the software behave in a predictable manner despite unexpected inputs or user actions is what [Defensive_programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) is all about.

Comment: This is not about defensive programming, unexpected inputs or user actions at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89878/discussion-between-ekostadinov-and-bartek-banachewicz).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,  ekostadinov. But as Bartek said, if users put a peach into a pear juicer, this design will have unexcepted result. So, do you have better solutions?

Comment: Let try to explain, again. The juicer works with `Fruit` abstraction (everything that is classified as fruit and have proper/expected water content), not concrete objects.  The juicer will work with any fruit as input and will produce juice (mixed or not), because the fruits allow to be squeezed. Everything that satisfies the Fruit contract should be a fruit, the thing Juicer works with.

Comment: The question, point 2: *One kind of juicer can only produce one kind of juice.*

Comment: The question point#1 : NOTE: there may be mixed juice (such as flavor of apple and pear)